# Is it possible in TypeScript to constrain a callback parameter based on the type of another parameter using generics?

Tags: typescript

I’m working on writing an event manager. The goal is for a user to be able to subscribe to events by passing in an event type and a callback function. My events are classes, so AwesomeEventType in the below example is the name of the class. I’m imagining something like this:

`eventManager.addEventListener(AwesomeEventType, (event: AwesomeEventType) => doSomething());`

To implement this, the definition of my addEventListener method looks like this:

```
addEventListener<T>(
    eventType: { new (...args: any[]): T},
    eventHandler: (event: T) => void
)
```

While that works and I can subscribe to events, TypeScript doesn’t seem to be checking that T is properly constrained. For example, I would expect the following to result in a build error, but it doesn’t:

`eventManager.addEventListener(AwesomeEventType, (event: DifferentEventType) => doSomething())`

Is it possible to get TypeScript to check that the callback parameter accepts the correct type and flags it as an error if it is not?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5GAW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: what is the structure of AwesomeEventType and DifferentEventType ?

Comment: @spmealin let me know if it works for you https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks reasonable to me, my guess is that you're being affect by TypeScript's type compatibility rules, which [even for classes (to the surprise of some) is structurally-based](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#relationships-between-classes). So this means that classes which don't have any explicit relationship can still be considered compatible with each other. So, for your code, here's examples of valid and invalid uses:

```
declare function addListener<T>(
    eventType: { new (...args: any[]): T},
    eventHandler: (event: T) => void
): void;

class EmptyEvent {}
class FooEvent { foo!: string }
class FooEvent2 { foo!: string }
class BarEvent { bar!: string }

// Valid
addListener(FooEvent, (event: FooEvent2) => {})
addListener(FooEvent, (event: EmptyEvent) => {});

// Invalid
addListener(EmptyEvent, (event: FooEvent) => {});
addListener(FooEvent, (event: BarEvent) => {})
```

You can deal with this by breaking the structural compatibility of your classes by simply adding a never used private field to them, such as in the example below:

```
class EmptyEvent { #_: undefined; }
class FooEvent { foo!: string; #_: undefined; }
class FooEvent2 { foo!: string; #_: undefined; }
class BarEvent { bar!: string; #_: undefined; }

// All invalid now
addListener(FooEvent, (event: FooEvent2) => {})
addListener(FooEvent, (event: EmptyEvent) => {});
addListener(EmptyEvent, (event: FooEvent) => {});
addListener(FooEvent, (event: BarEvent) => {})
```

There are other techniques to do this also, you can google "typescript type branding" or "typescript nominal typing" to check out ideas others have or libraries others have made to accomplish similar things.